# Iterated Function System Question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_0(x) = \frac{1}{3}x^3$ and $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{2}{3}$, where we consider both of these functions on $[0,1]$.  These two maps are 'almost' Lipschitz contractions on $[0,1]$, but their derivative at $x = 1$ is $1$, so they are not.

I am wondering if one can still claim that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \text{diam}(f_{i_1} \circ … \circ f_{i_n} ([0,1])) = 0$ for any sequence $i_1,…i_n,…$ where $i_j \in \{0,1\}$.  The notation $\text{diam}$ denotes the diameter of the subset.  This would then make this family of functions a so called weak hyperbolic IFS.  I am interested in this problem because I am trying to come up with examples of weak hyperbolic IFS's, that are not IFS's.

Comment: Well the first function converges uniformly to $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case where there are infinitely many $j=0$ is easy, since after $n$ instances of $j=0$, $[0,1]$ gets mapped to a subset of $[0,3^{-(3^{(n+1)}-1)/2}]$, whose diameter converges to zero.  The only other possibility is that $j=1$ for all $j>N$ for some finite $N$, so we have to consider the iterates of the one mapping $f_1$.  For me, it's slightly easier to think about when $0$ is the fixed point, so conjugate everything by the mapping $x\mapsto 1-x$: $$g(x)=1-f_1(1-x)=x-x^2+x^3/3.$$ If we set $$h(x)=\frac{x}{x+1},$$ then $h\geq g$ on $[0,1]$: indeed, $$h(x)-g(x)=\frac{x^3(2-x)}{3(1+x)}\geq 0.$$From this, it's easy to prove by induction that $$g^n([0,1])\subseteq h^n([0,1]) = \left[0,\frac{1}{n+1}\right],$$ so $$f_1^n([0,1])\subseteq \left[\frac{n}{n+1},1\right],$$ whose diameter also converges to zero.  Thus, the diameter converges to zero in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Darsh! This is very helpful.